# Start a video at a specific time using terminal

Tags: terminal, video, vlc

I want to be able to start a video, 30 seconds in, using the terminal. I'd prefer to use IINA because it's awesome, but VLC would work as well.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking. Do you mean start video playback in a separate window using a command from the terminal?

Comment: Just download `mpv` you don't make any issues. `mpv --start=Seconds`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --start-time 30 your_video.mp4
```

See [Documentation:Command line](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/) for other options.

Answer (score 1):

`/Applications/IINA.app/Contents/MacOS/iina-cli your_video.mp4 -- --no-resume-playback --start=0:30`

See the [mpv Reference Manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#options) for other options after the bare `--`.
The awkward order of options is explained by `iina-cli --help`.